# AS3 addChild with TextFields only showing the last one added

Tags: flash, actionscript, addchild

I'm building a Facebook client in actionscript, and I'm running into a problem. I have this block of code:

```
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);

        var feedResponse:String = (event.target.data);
        var object:Object = JSON.decode(feedResponse); //getting the data

        var friendsStatus:Array = new Array(); //array for status'
        var friendsName:Array = new Array(); //array for names

        var startX:int = 120;
        var startY:int = 100;

        var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        myFormat.size = 16;

        var statusMessage:TextField = new TextField();
        statusMessage.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
        statusMessage.wordWrap = true;
        statusMessage.width = 600;

        var faceFriend:TextField = new TextField();
        faceFriend.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
        faceFriend.wordWrap = true;
        faceFriend.width = 300;

        for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(object.data[i].message == undefined){
                var userStory:String = object.data[i].story; // mowing through the facebook JSON response
                friendsStatus[i] = userStory;
            } else {
                var userStatus:String = object.data[i].message;
                friendsStatus[i] = userStatus;
            }

            var fName:String = object.data[i].from.name;
            friendsName[i] = fName;
        } 

        for(var j:int; j < 10; j++) // The headache loop
        {
            faceFriend.x = startX;
            faceFriend.y = startY;

            faceFriend.text = friendsName[j]; //assign the current name to the TextField text property
            addChild(faceFriend); //add it to the stage
            startY += 30; //increase the y value so they dont overlap
            trace(startY);
            trace(faceFriend.text);
            trace("");

            statusMessage.x = startX;
            statusMessage.y = startY;

            statusMessage.text = friendsStatus[j]; //same here for the status'
            addChild(statusMessage);
            startY += 20;
            trace(startY);
            trace(statusMessage.text);
            trace("");
        }
```

which is supposed to loop through a set of status', assign them to variables and add them to the stage. However, all I achieve is the very last status being added to the stage.
As you can see from all the traces, I have discovered that all the arrays have the correct information, and the y value (so its not all on top of each other) is progressing correctly. It just refuses to let anything but the final TextField be visible :(

Any ideas?

P.S. I realise it's not exactly brilliant code - sorry for the headache in advance :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create

```
var faceFriend:textField inside the loop.
```

What you are currently doing is creating one text field and manipulating it over and over again. Which is causing a problem. This code will generate 10 fields and align them horizontally.

```
var faceFriend:TextField;

for(var i:uint;i<10;i++)
{
    faceFriend = new TextField();
    faceFriend.x = i*20;
    addChild(faceFriend);
}
```

whereas this code will generate one field manipulate it 10 times and show you one field , which is essentially what you are doing.

```
var facefriend:TextField = new TextField();

 for(var i:uint;i<10;i++)
 {
    faceFriend.x = i*20;
    addChild(faceFriend);
 }
```

This

Comment: Wow, thank you so much guys, this fixed my issue :) Can't believe I didn't think of it!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is create only 1 instance. Then you are setting the position in the loop, so the one you created originally is being moved.

To create 10 textfields, you need to create an instance inside the loop.

So you'll need to do

```
for(var i:int=0; i<10; i++) {
var faceFriend:TextField = new TextField();
faceFriend.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
faceFriend.wordWrap = true;
faceFriend.width = 300;
//Everything else
}
```